# Retrieve data from 2013 WorkFlow Start Task Process Task

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, tasks

First, I cannot use the 2010 SPD platform.

I have built a custom 2013 SPD workflow that has conditional approvers. Currently, I have conditional statements that build a 'email list' variable with various users that is then used as the argument for the 'Start Task Approval' action.

I need to be able to retrieve feedback from these users if they reject it. I realize there is no task ID like with the 'Assign a Task' action, but is there any work around to get feedback from these approvers? Or perhaps break them into individual task assignments that are nested in a parallel block?

Any guidance/help with this will be much appreciated!